# How to hide internal geometry of a transparent object

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency

I have an existing character model I'm attempting to render with a 'hologram' like effect (Fresnel, alpha, etc) applied as part of a scene using Cycles.

The model has three existing materials (body, accessories, eyes).

However, quite a lot of the interior geometry such as the details inside the mouth and the eye balls are visible through the main body mesh.

How do I make sure anything 'internal' to the character is still correctly hidden as though the model was opaque?

All three materials use a matching node network to the one below with just different texture images applied.

[image: Render Preview]
[image: Effect Node Network]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following up from [Crantisz answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/253706/106636) which didn't quite work but gave me a clue of which Node to use, I found that the Ray Length property gave the right results.

Along with making sure the primary body was the last material on the list.

I also added a round up for the accessories material where the hair fringe comes down slightly in front of the face.

[image: Body and Eyes Network]
Body and Eyes

[image: Accessories Network]
Accessories

[image: Material Order]
Material Order

[image: End Result]
End Result

Comment: Geometry -> backfacing might be an elegant solution

Answer (score 5):

You can use **light path** node for this. **Transparent depth** will be more or equal to 1 for secondary bounces. So you can use this information to set fully transparent material for secondary bounces.

[image]

Comment: That was almost the right answer for my solution and was a good clue, I've followed up with my working solution in another answer.